# Faster pattern matching

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I need to write a pattern matcher that will print out *all* combinations that could possibly match, and the patterns can be subpatterns of one another e.g. pattern eee is a subpattern of eeeff.

```
Input: weeeffeeef
Patterns: weee, eee, eeeff, f, w
```

As you can see there are multiple valid matching sequences e.g.

- weee, eee, f, f, eee, f
- w, eee, f, f, eee, f
- w, eeeff, eee, f

Etc. Is there a way to find all these patterns without taking a huge amount of time?

There is no ''right'' sequence by the way. The short patterns are just as valid as the long ones i.e. this is not a compression algorithm. I just need all sequences.

Comment: Backtracking should work here. I don't think performance will be an issue unless the inputs are really big.

Comment: The number of possibilities could be enormous. Consider input `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` and patterns `"a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa"`. Etc. "I just need all sequences" may be a lot to ask for.

Comment: Well, I'm not the user of this code. I'm just being asked to implement it. My hunch was that I should just use recursion. However it was looking like this would be O(n^3) or O(2^n), I can't quite tell which.

Comment: Maybe look at KMP https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: @stark `O(n³)` or `O(n²)` makes no sense here - what is `n`? You have much more variables that characterise the run time complexity depending on the input: length of the string, number of patterns, average length of each pattern, frequency of matches of patterns in the string

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm will use backtracking:

```
function solve(input, patterns, curr_sequence) {
  if (input.is_empty):
    yield curr_sequence
  else
    foreach pattern in patterns:
      if (input.starts_with(pattern)):
        yield* solve(input.slice(pattern.length), patterns, curr_sequence.concat([pattern]))
}
```

This is probably fast enough for simple inputs. If you need to optimise this for huge input strings, large number of patterns and huge patterns, where the patterns match sparsely (so that the sheer number of generated sequences does not dominate the running time), I would:

- instead of slicing the input string every time, which might involve copying (depends on the string implementation), pass through only a `curr_index` and then use `input.matches_at(pattern, curr_index)` instead of `starts_with`
- instead of creating a new `curr_sequence` array by concatenation (which involves copying) at every recursive call, use a mutable array and copy it only when actually `yield`ing it after a successful match at the end of the string. Alternatively, use a linked list with `O(1)` prepend and reverse it at the end, use a reverse list instead of an array so that you can benefit from sharing begins, or use a list and run the algorithm in reverse so that you can benefit from sharing tails. Sharing helps in particular if you expect lots of result sequences.
- instead of repeatedly searching the same suffix for the same patterns, just with a different `curr_sequence`, use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_science)
- or, instead of repeatedly using `matches_at` at the same position in the string, with the same patterns, memoise the matches or simply compute up-front which patterns match where in the string
- to compute which patterns match where in the string, build a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)